# DPDK MLX5 PMD driver probe issue

Tags: networking, linux-device-driver, dpdk

I'm not able to use the mlx5 pmd driver with some Mellanox NICs I have installed on my server. The error I'm receiving during EAL initialization is:

et_mlx5: no Verbs device matches PCI device 0000:03:00.0, are kernel drivers loaded?

The DPDK version I'm currently using is: DPDK-STABLE-18.11

I have installed the OFED latest version:

mlnx-en-4.5-1.0.1.0-ubuntu16.04-x86_64

I have performed modprobe of the ib_uverbs kernel module

Here's the kernel version I'm using

```
moragalu@server:~$ uname -r
4.4.0-143-generic
```

Here are the NIC models:

```
moragalu@server:~$ lspci | grep Mell
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27710 Family [ConnectX-4 Lx]
03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27710 Family [ConnectX-4 Lx]
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27710 Family [ConnectX-4 Lx]
06:00.1 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27710 Family [ConnectX-4 Lx]
```

The firmware version that the NICs are using:

```
moragalu@eridium03:~$ ethtool -i eridium25-03
driver: mlx5_core
version: 4.5-1.0.1
firmware-version: 14.24.1000 (MT_2420110034)
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:06:00.1
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

The complete output is of the eal initialization is:

```
EAL: Detected 16 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: No free hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: PCI device 0000:03:00.0 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 15b3:1015 net_mlx5
net_mlx5: no Verbs device matches PCI device 0000:03:00.0, are kernel drivers loaded?
EAL: Requested device 0000:03:00.0 cannot be used
EAL: PCI device 0000:03:00.1 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 15b3:1015 net_mlx5
net_mlx5: no Verbs device matches PCI device 0000:03:00.1, are kernel drivers loaded?
EAL: Requested device 0000:03:00.1 cannot be used
EAL: PCI device 0000:06:00.0 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 15b3:1015 net_mlx5
net_mlx5: no Verbs device matches PCI device 0000:06:00.0, are kernel drivers loaded?
EAL: Requested device 0000:06:00.0 cannot be used
EAL: PCI device 0000:06:00.1 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 15b3:1015 net_mlx5
net_mlx5: no Verbs device matches PCI device 0000:06:00.1, are kernel drivers loaded?
EAL: Requested device 0000:06:00.1 cannot be used
EAL: PCI device 0000:03:00.1 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 15b3:1015 net_mlx5
net_mlx5: no Verbs device matches PCI device 0000:03:00.1, are kernel drivers loaded?
EAL: Driver cannot attach the device (03:00.1)
EAL: Failed to attach device on primary process
```

Current modules loaded in the kernel:

```
moragalu@eridium03:~$ lsmod | grep ib
mlx5_ib                16384  0
mlx_compat             24576  4 mlx4_en,mlx5_ib,mlx4_core,mlx5_core
ib_uverbs              61440  0
ib_iser                49152  0
rdma_cm                49152  1 ib_iser
ib_cm                  49152  1 rdma_cm
ib_sa                  36864  2 rdma_cm,ib_cm
ib_mad                 49152  2 ib_cm,ib_sa
ib_core               106496  7 rdma_cm,ib_cm,ib_sa,iw_cm,ib_mad,ib_iser,ib_uverbs
ib_addr                20480  2 rdma_cm,ib_core
```

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problems when using the RDMA-core libraries for the ibverbs dependency. In the past I've managed to find a bug in mlx5_core.c (hardcoded the no of queues to 8 in the probe function and it magically worked), but I'm not sure it's the same issue for you.

Either way, the problem went away when I installed the latest [Mellanox OFED Drivers](http://www.mellanox.com/page/products_dyn?product_family=26), so it's a good idea to try that. Just remember to install it using the command:

```
mlnxofedinstall --dpdk --upstream-libs
```

edit: Just noticed you have the drivers installed - make sure you did the installation as above. One more thing you can do: check the output of this (compiled with `-libverbs`):

```
#include <infiniband/verbs.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
        struct ibv_device ** devices;
        int num;
        struct ibv_context * ctx;
        devices = ibv_get_device_list(&num);
        int i;
        if(devices[0] == NULL)
                printf("devices is null\n");
        printf("got %d devices\n", num);
        for (i=0;i<num;i++) {
                printf(ibv_get_device_name(devices[i]));
                printf("\n");
                ctx = ibv_open_device(devices[i]);
                if (ctx == NULL)
                        printf("ctx is null \n");
                else
                        printf("device opened\n");
        }
        if (errno)
                printf("ERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        ibv_free_device_list(devices);
return 0;
}
```

If it lists no devices at least you'll know it's an issue with the verbs drivers and not DPDK itself.